# Как задать условие для чтения с Excel файла формата Date отдельно времени и даты?

Tags: java, excel, poi

написал условие для определения типа столбцов, которое должно определить столбец времени или даты, только при запуске ни чего не выводит, подскажите пожалуйста в чем моя ошибка...

```
public List<String> extractExcelContentByColumnIndex(int columnIndex) {
    LinkedList<String> columndata = null;
    String fileName = "PrimerRaspisania.xlsx";
    try {
        File f = new File(fileName);
        FileInputStream ios = new FileInputStream(f);
        XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(ios);
        XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
        Iterator<Row> rowIterator = sheet.iterator();
        columndata = new LinkedList<>();

        while (rowIterator.hasNext()) {
            Row row = rowIterator.next();
            Iterator<Cell> cellIterator = row.cellIterator();
            while (cellIterator.hasNext()) {
                Cell cell = cellIterator.next();
                
                if (row.getRowNum() > 0) { //To filter column headings
                    if (cell.getColumnIndex() == columnIndex) {// To match column index
                        switch (cell.getCellType()) {
                            case Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC:

                                if (DateUtil.isCellDateFormatted(cell)) {
                                    String date = "dd.MM.yyyy";
                                    String time = "HH:mm";
                                    String cellSt = cell.toString();
                                        SimpleDateFormat sdfd = new SimpleDateFormat(date);
                                       if (cellSt == date) { 
                                        columndata.add(sdfd.format(cell.getDateCellValue()));
                                    } 
                                        SimpleDateFormat sdft = new SimpleDateFormat(time, Locale.UK); // дата в формате 24 часа
                                        if (cellSt == time) {
                                        columndata.add(sdft.format(cell.getDateCellValue()));
                                    }
                                } else {
                                    columndata.add((int) cell.getNumericCellValue() + "");
                                }
                                break;
                            case Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING:

                                columndata.add(cell.getStringCellValue());
                                break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        ios.close();
        Iterator it = columndata.iterator();
        while (it.hasNext()) {
            System.out.println(it.next());
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return columndata;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы сравниваете строковое значение ячейки с паттернами парсинга даты\времени - `cellSt == date` и `cellSt == time`, что является ошибкой. Вместо этого, вам нужно попытаться спарсить дату\время из строки и только после успешного парсинга добавлять найденное значение в коллекцию `columnData`

Comment: Также будет более оптимальным вариантом сначала произвести поиск в первой строке, запомнить индексы колонок с датами\временем, и уже после этого итерировать по всем строкам, забирая данные уже из конкретных столбцов (если известно, что столбцы с датами\временем не содержат пустых ячеек). Так вы избежите большого кол-ва лишних попыток найти дату в уже проверенном столбце.

Comment: Также стоит обратить внимание на метод [Cell.getDateCellValue()](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Cell.html#getDateCellValue--)

Comment: т.е. нужно через Local Date парсить?

Comment: @AleKs, можно воспользоваться методом, что я указал во втором комментарии, или же SimpleDateFormat

Comment: что то не понятно как этот parse работает, врое он принимает переменную класса ParsePosition, либо без нее выкидывает NullPoint, но создав эту переменную, почему то просит на стринг её изменить, почему так?

Comment: @AleKs, попробуйте использовать метод getDateCellValue()